# npm vulnerabilities require manual review npm audit fix not working

Tags: security, npm

I'm losing my mind trying to resolve this, it says that I have 78 vulnerabillities. Please help me fix this.
I don''t know where to change the code, or how to chage it.

[image]

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&google&read your error messages, not critique your use of color and perspective.

Answer (score 0):

So, i was building a cordova app, and in my packege.json there was a dependecy called "cordova-plugin-browsersync": "^1.1.0", and i saw that this packege was updated at 3 yeas ago, so there was a new version, called "cordova-plugin-browsersync-gen2": "^1.1.7", and I replaced the dependecy and it worked. Hope I can help someone with this.